# Add current site's domain to template dirs

Tags: django, django-templates, django-sites

What is the correct way to prepend an extra, site-specific templates directory to the template dirs setting in Django?

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            <PREPEND SITE-BASED TEMPLATE DIR IN HERE>
            str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I obviously can't use Site.objects.get_current() in there.

I could write my own template loader which uses it but is that "correct"?

Or should I be using an extended version of the settings files or something?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, start by separating the settings. You should have a settings hierarchy that goes like:

```
base_settings.py
siteA_settings.py
siteB_settings.py
```

On `base_settings.py` you should put all the settings that are project-wide.
`siteA_settings.py` (which is a child) will override the `base_settings`.

To make it site-specific you have to put on each setting file the `SITE_ID` setting. Example of `siteA_settings.py`

```
# Sites Framework
SITE_ID = 1
SITE_TITLE = 'First Site'
```

Then load the `TEMPLATES` settings. They can be different on each setting file. Example:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
 ... , etc.
```

Just like TEMPLATES, you can choose to have different settings for each Site (apps, email settings etc)

Then, when you run the server, you should specify which setting (site) you want to run. Example:

`python manage.py runserver --settings=myproject.siteA_settings`

where `myproject` is the app where your settings are located.

*Do not forget that you have to put the `--settings` argument everytime you run a command (including makemigrations, migrate, etc etc)*

---

Usually, on my projects, I create a `core` app, a `settings` directory and inside it, I put  `base_settings.py`, `dev.py`, `local.py`, `production.py` etc. When running the Django Development Server, I then run the command:

`python manage.py runserver --settings=core.settings.local`

Comment: That isn't site specific, is it?

Comment: @bodger BASE_DIR is the absolute path to the Django project and the other line joins the directories to your abs path.

Ps: What do you mean by "site-specific"? Different settings that apply to different environments?

Comment: By site-specific, I mean that it uses the Sites framework. I need the code to use different templates for each Site.

Comment: @bodger I understood your question. Take a look now because I updated and changed the whole answer. It should solve your issue :)

Comment: That makes more sense. But shouldn't there be a way for it to work out the DIRS value from the domain of the Site or something? That's what I've done in a custom template loader. I just wondered if there was another way, using settings, which didn't require me to redefine the whole of the TEMPLATES setting.